# Add Cache Policy to Amazon (OVH) S3 Bucket Images

Tags: amazon-s3, cache-control, ovh

I'm facing a problem related to cache headers for images stored in an Amazon (OVH) S3 bucket. While testing my website's performance with Google Lighthouse, I received a recommendation to "Serve static assets with an efficient cache policy." for S3 files.

To provide some context, I'm utilizing an S3 bucket from OVH to host the images for my website. The current setup involves generating pre-signed URLs for these images via a PHP script. However, when I analyzed the results from Google Lighthouse, it pointed out that the S3 images are lacking cache rules.

Is there any configurations or parameters within the S3 API that could help me achieve this ? Unfortunately, I couldn't find relevant information within OVH's documentation. As it's an OVH S3 bucket i don't have access to AWS command line or any other command line...

I'm reaching out to the community to seek advice or suggestions on how to efficiently manage caching headers for images stored in an S3 bucket. If anyone has experience with optimizing caching for pre-signed URLs or knows of any S3 API parameters that could assist in this way, I would greatly appreciate your insights :)

Here is an extract from my php S3 Class if needed by it's quite close to the sample provided in OVH S3 documentation :

```
  public function getPresignedUrl($s3Key){
        $this->connectToS3() ;
        // le timestamp de l'url signée date d'il y a 6 jours ou plus, il faut redemander une url et mettre à jour la base

        $cmd = $this->s3->getCommand('GetObject', [
            'Bucket' => $this->s3BucketName,
            'Key' => $s3Key
        ]);

        $request = $this->s3->createPresignedRequest($cmd, '+1 week');
        return (string) $request->getUri();
    }

    public function addFileToBucket($filePath, $s3Key = NULL, $generateThumbnail = false, $generateWebp = false){
        $this->connectToS3() ;
        if (empty($s3Key)) {
            $s3Key = "local-file-" . uniqid();
        }
        try {
            $this->s3->putObject([
                'Bucket' =>$this->s3BucketName,
                'Key' => $s3Key,
                'SourceFile' => $filePath
            ]);
            new Log("Ajout du fichier : ".$s3Key." () au bucket", false) ;

            $url = $this->getPresignedUrl($s3Key) ;
            $extension = strtolower(substr(strrchr($filePath, '.'), 1));

            $this->db_file = new db_file($this->page);

            $this->db_file->file_key = $s3Key ;
            $this->db_file->file_last_s3_time = timestampToSql(time()) ;
            $this->db_file->file_url = $url ;
            $this->db_file->file_extension = $extension ;
            $this->db_file->save() ;

            if (in_array($extension,$this->images_extensions) && $generateThumbnail){
                $this->generateThumbnail($s3Key);
            }

            if (in_array($extension,$this->images_extensions) && $extension  != "webp" && $generateWebp){
                $this->generateWebp($s3Key);
            }

        } catch (Exception $exception) {
            new Log("Failed to upload $s3Key with error: " . $exception->getMessage());
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

S3 does not offer a native caching mechanism.

[As stated in the official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/whitepapers/latest/s3-optimizing-performance-best-practices/using-caching-for-frequently-accessed-content.html), you can implement caching for a bucket using AWS services like CloudFront, ElastiCache, or MediaStore, or by using an external service.